# Key getting changed in Reducer

Tags: hadoop

I have taken Text as the key in Mapper class. However, when I go to Reducer class, the Key's are getting changed. Below is an example.

The key in Mapper are :

20130101
20130102
20130103

However, in Reducer class, the keys are as below:

20130101

Keys like 20130102 & 20130103 are getting replaced by 20130101.

Comment: Please show code demonstrating how you're accessing the keys in the reducer.

Comment: I am accessing the key in the Reducer class as below :String strKey = key.toString() . This is inside the reduce method.

Comment: I am accessing the key in the Reducer class as below :String strKey = key.toString() . This is inside the reduce method.Below are the code snippet:  Mapper : inside map method : String[] strArray = line.split(" ");strKey = strArray[1].toString().trim();context.write(new Text(strKey), new Text(strArray[12].trim())); Reducer: Inside reduce method: String str_Key = key.toString();

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not copying the value out of the key. Hadoop does some obnoxiously unexpected things in the name of optimization, particularly [object reuse](http://wikidoop.com/wiki/Hadoop/ObjectReuse).

So when you think you're getting different `Text` instances, you're really getting the same one. If you're putting these `Text` keys into a list or map, for example, it's not going to work as you expect unless you copy the values.